# VSTS: Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Not a valid reference 'origin/development'

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

**Edit - This issue seems to have (at least temporarily) resolved itself - I have no idea why and I have not changed anything to make it work - I'll update if it breaks again**

I used Git-TF (https://gittf.codeplex.com/) to move our existing Team Foundation Version Control repo to a new Git repo (both repos in the same VSTS Project).

It all appeared to work correctly. However now we have lots of issues.

- Trying to push changes from a local branch to a remote branch gets the following error:

`Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Not a valid reference 'origin/development'`

- Using the Sync command, however, does work and pushes changes successfully to remote.
- Perhaps the biggest problem - we've only be able to get a Pull Request to work once. Now every Pull Request is throwing `405 error` for everything we try to do (abandon / accept - it all throws the same 405 Error)

[image]

**Edit: Steps Taken to setup the Git repo**

1. Downloaded and installed Git and Git-tf on my local machine
2. Cloned the TFVC repo locally via git-tf
3. Created a new Git Repo via VSTS
4. Set the new repo as remote on my local machine
5. Pushed the full history to the Git Repo

**Steps taken once the Git repo was established**

1. Created a development branch from the master
2. Checked the development branch out locally via Vis Studio
3. Created a new local branch from the local development branch
4. Made changes and a few commits
5. Publish the local branch to remotes
6. Click on "Create a Pull Request" from Vis Studio
7. Local Source Branch: test-branch, Remote target: development - then click Create
8. No Merge Conflicts, I review my own work and Accept - so far so good
9. Click on Complete Pull Request, leave "delete branch after merge" selected and click Complete Merge
10. **And this time it's worked...infuriatingly... The last 2 days it hasn't worked...**

Back to square one until I can repeat the process it seems.

Comment: Can you share the steps how do you configure these? I just tried with git-tf to move a TFVC repo to Git repo and perform push and pull request actions, but didn't see any issue.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT: Sure, what config would you like to know? I'll edit my question with the steps I've taken to try to add some context.

Comment: The general steps from cloning the TFVC repo via git-tf tool.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT: I've added the steps for posterity, however I just recreated the steps for a Pull Request and it's worked as expected this time (after not working multiple times for multiple team members over the past 2 days). Thanks for your help, unless I can re-create it I can't see how I can resolve it. If you see any issues with the way I initially setup the repo please do let me know though as I have a feeling this isn't truly resolved

Comment: `git-tf` is shitty at best, but use it to create a git repo to conserve history, then create a proper VSTS git repo instead and use that. Much less painful.

Comment: I followed your steps but didn't see any issue.

Comment: @leppie that's exactly what we did. It was a one-off to move from TFVC to VSTS Git. Ideally never using it again! :)

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Appreciate the feedback. Thanks!

Comment: This is happening to me with every git repo I clone from GitHub, it's very frustrating. @Eddie-MSFT I can reliably reproduce this issue if you're interested.

Comment: I should also point out that if I right-click on my local branch in Visual Studio under "Branches" in Team Explorer and do a Push, this is where it fails. If I go to "Sync" and do a Push under Outgoing Commits, it works fine.

Answer (score 11):

Try right-click on my local branch in Visual Studio under "Branches" in Team Explorer and do a Push, this is where it fails. If I go to "Sync" and do a Push under Outgoing Commits, it works fine.

Comment: Still having this issue. Wonder if they'll ever fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me and I resolved it by going to my Repository Settings in Team Explorer > Settings and updating the settings under "Remotes". Origin was set incorrectly to a local git instance.